# Thymeleaf classappend for multiple classes

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to add multiple classes using condition.

```
<div th:classappend="x.isTrue ?'class1' "  ></div>
```

I want something like

```
<div th:classappend="x.isTrue ?'class1' and "y.isTrue ?'class2'"  ></div>
```

Answer (score 46):

You can use [literal substitutions](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) to achieve this:

```
<div th:classappend="|${x.isTrue ? 'class1' : ''} ${y.isTrue ? 'class2' : ''}|"></div>
```

Another method is to simply wrap your conditions with brackets and concatenate them:

```
<div th:classappend="${(x.isTrue ? 'class1' : '') + (y.isTrue ? ' class2' : '')}"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but sorry, it doesn´t work for me:
 Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(x.isTrue ? 'class1' : '') + (y.isTure ? ' class2' : '')"

Comment: @Heisenberg you may have misspelled `isTrue`

Comment: @vphilipnyc oh... you are right, but it was because I copied it from the original answer where it is misspelled. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution. It works very well for me.

```
<span class="oi" th:classappend="${(h.tipo.label =='Sim/Não' ? 'oi-signpost': '') + 
                                (h.tipo.label =='Quantidade' ? 'oi-target': '')+
                                 (h.tipo.label =='Evitar' ? 'oi-shield': '')}"
                                 title="Visualizar"
                                    aria-hidden="true"></span>
```